# Convert Vec<Cow<'_, [u8]> to &str

Tags: rust

A lib (quick_xml) function (attributes()) returns a value with a type `Vec<Cow<'_, [u8]>`.

The exact line is `e.attributes().map(|a| a.unwrap().value).collect::<Vec<_>>()` and the printed value = `[[116, 101, 115, 116]]`.

How can I convert it to a string ("test" in this case) so I can use it later?

Comment: From your description it's difficult to understand what you're trying you do. A lot of rust types implement the to_string() method. maybe you can try that.

Comment: Note that you possibly want to use not `&str`, but `String`, since the former can't exist when the original `Vec<Cow<>>` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referencing [this example](https://github.com/tafia/quick-xml/tree/a4be48431a2c512683538b81d7ee037af70d5cce#reader). In the future, please give us the whole source code – this makes answering the question much easier.

---

## Understanding the code

Let's take it one step at a time:

1. ```
   e.attributes().map(|a| a.unwrap().value).collect::<Vec<_>>()
   ^
   ```

   `e` is a [`BytesStart` struct](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.22.0/quick_xml/events/struct.BytesStart.html), so it represents an opening XML tag, in your case `<tag1 att1 = "test">`.
2. ```
   e.attributes().map(|a| a.unwrap().value).collect::<Vec<_>>()
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   This is [the `attributes` method of `BytesStart`](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.22.0/quick_xml/events/struct.BytesStart.html#method.attributes). It returns [the `Attributes` struct](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.22.0/quick_xml/events/attributes/struct.Attributes.html) which represents the set of attributes that one tag has. In your case, that is only one attribute: It has the name `attr1` and the value `test`.

   [`Attributes` is an iterator](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.22.0/quick_xml/events/attributes/struct.Attributes.html#impl-Iterator), this means you can iterate over the contained [`Attribute`](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.22.0/quick_xml/events/attributes/struct.Attribute.html)s (note that [`Attributes`](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.22.0/quick_xml/events/attributes/struct.Attributes.html) contains multiple [`Attribute`](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.22.0/quick_xml/events/attributes/struct.Attribute.html)s – these are not the same type!). If you want to learn more about iterators, you may want to read [the chapter about it in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html).
3. ```
   e.attributes().map(|a| a.unwrap().value).collect::<Vec<_>>()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   Here, we call [the `map` method of the `Iterator` struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map). It lets us transform one iterator (in this case the `Attributes` struct) into another iterator by transforming each value of the iterator. We call it with a closure (if you don't know what this is, [the Rust book also has a chapter about this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html)) that takes one value of the original iterator and returns the transformed value of the new iterator. Now, let's look at that iterator:

   1. ```
      |a| a.unwrap().value
      ^^^
      ```

      This iterator takes one argument named `a`, which is, as I said above, the type that the original iterator contains. I said above that `Attributes` contains multiple `Attribute`s – while this is true, it is not the full picture, the iterator iterates over `Result<Attribute>`, and that is the type of `a`.
   2. ```
      |a| a.unwrap().value
          ^^^^^^^^^^
      ```

      When operating normally, `a` will always be an instance of [`Result::Ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Ok) containing your `Attribute`, but if your XML is somehow invalid, `a`may also be a [`Result::Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err) to indicate some kind of parse error. We don't want to care about error handling here, so we just call [the `unwrap` method of `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) that returns the contained `Argument` and panics if there was an error.
   3. ```
      |a| a.unwrap().value
                     ^^^^^
      ```

      The `Attribute` struct contains two values: [`key`](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.22.0/quick_xml/events/attributes/struct.Attribute.html#structfield.key) and [`value`]. We are only interested in `value`, so let's select it. The `value` field is of type `Cow<'a, [u8]>`. Cow is a smart pointer with some interesting properties that aren't really relevant here. If you want to learn more about it, you may be interested in [the documentation of `Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) (although his may be a bit too complicated for a Rust newbie). For the remainder of this explanation, I will just pretend `value` is of type `&[u8]` (a reference to a `u8` slice).
   4. We now have determined that the closure returns a `&[u8]`, therefore the iterator returned by `map` iterates over `&[u8]`.
4. ```
   e.attributes().map(|a| a.unwrap().value).collect::<Vec<_>>()
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   Now we call [the `collect` method of `Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) which transforms the iterator into a collection. The type of the collection is given as a generic parameter an is `Vec<_>`. The underscore tells rustc to try to find out the correct type by context or output an error if this is not possible. The only type possible here is `&[u8]`, therefore, this method returns a `Vec<&[u8]>`.

## The solution

You can use the [`unescape_and_decode_value` method of `Attribute`](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.22.0/quick_xml/events/attributes/struct.Attribute.html#method.unescape_and_decode_value). This transforms the `Attribute` value to a `String` and also unescapes escape sequences if the attribute contains them.

```
e.attributes().map(|a| a.unwrap().unescape_and_decode_value(&reader).unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

Note that this still returns `Vector<String>`, not `String`. The vector contains the values of all attributes assigned to this element – in this case, it's just the attribute value "Test".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::str::from_utf8` for fallible conversion of `&[u8]` to `&str`:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let s = "test";
    let v = s.as_bytes();
    let c = Cow::Borrowed(v);
    println!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&*c).unwrap());
}
```

The crucial part is the deref and reborrow of `Cow` since `from_utf8` takes `&[u8]` instead of `Cow`. `Cow` implements `Deref` for `T`, in this case `T` is `[u8]`, thus you can get a `&[u8]` via `&*`.

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=530fd34ca21f44731c085ba4c5411512)

In your concrete example you should be able to get a `Vec<&str>` by:

```
e.attributes().map(|a| std::str::from_utf8(&*a.unwrap().value).unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```